# Get all cookies from a page using cURL PHP

Tags: php, curl

[image]
I'm trying to access a page using PHP's cURL, this page is to return 2 cookies in the "Response Headers", but in the cURL header only returns the first one.

Does anyone know if there might be some block on the page, and how to work around this problem?

> This cookie is generated on a "Status Code: 302"

I've already tried to get "file_get_contents" and also tried to do the
`"CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION"` function and I also know success
OBS: The function to break the google captcha is already working.

```
$url = 'https://pje.trt15.jus.br/captcha/login_post.php';

$post = [
        'g-recaptcha-response' => $g_response,
        'referer'              => '/consultaprocessual/pages/consultas/ConsultaProcessual.seam',
        'random'               => $g_captcha_random,
        'entrar'               => $g_captcha_entrar
    ];

    if( $g_captcha_enviar != null )
        $post[$g_captcha_enviar] = 'Enviar';

    if( $g_captcha_entrar != null )
        $post['entrar'] = $g_captcha_entrar;


    $post_http = http_build_query($post);

    $headers = [
        ':authority: pje.trt15.jus.br',
        ':method: POST',
        ':path: /captcha/login_post.php',
        ':scheme: https',
        'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
        //'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br',
        'accept-language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
        'cache-control: no-cache',
        'content-length: ' . strlen($post_http),
        'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'cookie: '.$cookie_captchasess.' _ga=GA1.3.1830456077.1560269951; _gid=GA1.3.249690674.1560269951',
        'origin: https://pje.trt15.jus.br',
        'referer: https://pje.trt15.jus.br/consultaprocessual/pages/consultas/ConsultaProcessual.seam',
        'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1'
    ];

    $options = [
        CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION   => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER          => true,
        CURLOPT_POST            => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => $post_http,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => $headers,
        CURLOPT_COOKIE          => $cookie_captchasess,
        CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT   => true,
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE         => true,
        CURLOPT_REDIR_PROTOCOLS => CURLPROTO_HTTPS,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING        => 'gzip, deflate',

        CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 40,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => $user_agent,
    ];

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $resp = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    echo "<pre>";
    echo $resp;
```

Comment: Use Google Chrome's F12 developer tools to check whether or not the page is expecting you to *send* a cookie or nonce or POST/GET field(s) before it will send you back the second cookie.

Comment: So I used the google chorme developer tool, followed all the paths that the requisitions do
However accessing directly through the browser the two cookies are is generated, but by cURL is returned only the first cookie. I do not know if there is any blockage.